# php : Warning: ftp_put(): Could not open data connection to port xxxxxx: Connection timed out

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to copy files from server A(Domain A) to server B(Domain B).

First i had tried to connect through

```
ftp_connect( "ftp.ServerA.Com", 21 );
```

but it gives error

```
"Clear texts are not allowed"
```

so i had changed with

```
ftp_ssl_connect( "ftp.ServerA.Com", 21 );
```

its connect perfectly.

not the problem is : when i am trying to use

```
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)
```

it creates a file on ServerB but it contains nothing, in terms of file size it always shows 0 KB. and it process a lot of time and at the end it returns with below line :

```
ftp_put(): Could not open data connection to port xxxxxx: Connection timed out.
```

i asked my hosting provider they suggest me to use "ftpes" instead of "ftp".

i searched alot in google but nothing happened . so can anyone!

### **Edit**

Full code :

```
<?php 
    $settings = array(
        'host'    =>    'ftp.XXXX.in',              // * the ftp-server hostname
        'user'    =>    'XXXX',                 // * ftp-user
        'pass'    =>    'XXXX',                 // * ftp-password
    );


    $connection = @ftp_ssl_connect( $settings['host'], 21 );

    $login = ftp_login( $connection, $settings['user'], $settings['pass'] );
    ftp_pasv($connection, true) or die("Cannot switch to passive mode");        
    if ( !$connection || !$login ) {
        die('Connection attempt failed, Check your settings');
    }
    if( @ftp_put( $connection, "text.txt", "test.txt", FTP_BINARY ) ) 
        echo "done";
    else
        echo "not";
    ftp_close($connection);
```

?>

Comment: did you close the ftp connection?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy : Yes, if i do vice versa[means from Copy files from ServerB to ServerA] then it works perfectly, even i had tried with passive mode, but it return false.

Comment: Do you mean that `ftp_get` works while `ftp_put` does not? Can you upload using a command-line `ftp` client from A to B? With passive mode, do you get any error message? Show us your complete code for passive mode attempt.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : nope. not by using ftp_get(), i use this whole code on my serverB, just changed credentials.

Comment: Again:  With the passive mode, what error messages/warnings do you get? What returns `false`? Th `ftp_put`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : ftp_pasv() returns false and after long process     ftp_put gives : Warning: ftp_put(): Could not open data connection to port xxxxxx: Connection timed out

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : it reply with : `Warning: ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: if is use `ftp_pasv` then i have to face this message : `Warning: ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)` | or if i dont use `ftp_pasv` then message will be `Warning: ftp_put(): Could not open data connection to port 55902: Connection timed out`

Comment: Does the `ftp_pasv` issue any error/warning?

Comment: *ftp_pasv() returns false and after long process ftp_put gives : Warning: ftp_put(): Could not open data connection to port xxxxxx: Connection timed out*: Your code does not get to `ftp_put` when `ftp_pasv` return false, so how do you get an error message from `ftp_put`?

Comment: Show us a log file from FTP server on Server B for the session with failing `ftp_pasv`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : i had just tested, `ftp_pasv($con, true)` returns with 1

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Log : `[07-Mar-2016 08:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in /home/newbb/public_html/try.php on line 22
[07-Mar-2016 08:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  ftp_put(): TYPE is now 8-bit binary in /home/newbb/public_html/try.php on line 22
[07-Mar-2016 08:47:03 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: connection in /home/newbb/public_html/try.php on line 28
[07-Mar-2016 08:47:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  ftp_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/newbb/public_html/try.php on line 28`

Comment: Again: *Can you upload using a command-line ftp client from A to B?*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : I hadn't tried it yet, and one more thing  "i dont know how to do it"

Comment: See [How to upload one file by FTP from command line?](http://superuser.com/q/323214/213663).